# What IP addresses and ports are required for firewall exceptions for Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: discussion, support, firewall

While using the Stack Exchange sites, image uploading is restricted in my office by default and I need to request an exception to interact with Stack Exchange sites (*i.e., post questions answers with **images**, etc.*). My office requires me to provide an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Port_number), or URLs. So what URLs and ports should I give them to open access for me?

I was thinking to give them,

```
URLs

https://stackoverflow.com/
https://*.stackoverflow.com/
https://*.stackexchange.com/

PORT: 80
```

**Is there a guideline?**

Comment: a lot of images are hosted at stack.imgur.com

Comment: There should be some guideline from SO regarding firewall exception requests. @DaveCousineau

Answer (score -1):

The port should be 443 and 80.

For the IP address, use the following:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.    3600    IN    A    151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com.    3600    IN    A    151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com.    3600    IN    A    151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com.    3600    IN    A    151.101.65.69
```

(I've got it with `dig stackoverflow.com`), but be ready to update them from time to time.

Comment: `URL stackoverflow.com`. Will it work for all sites?

Comment: Not nesessary, as mentioned in other comments, it's also `stack.imgur.com`, which is Amazon and yes, developers *may rethink it at any moment*. So, you will never have a warranty that your fixes are *permanent*