# Accessing Stack Exchange API behind a firewall - are there IP address ranges to whitelist?

Tags: support, api, ip-address

**Scenario**

I am calling Stack Exchange APIs to collect Stack Overflow Teams data for my organization. In order to call these APIs from the server where I would like to run it, I must first request firewall traffic to be allowed for the APIs from the server.

There is a mechanism we could use to whitelist the domain name, but this works by looking up the address of the domain periodically and updating firewall access.  Unfortunately sometimes this leads to the application getting/using an IP address which hasn't been set up in the firewall yet, and getting blocked.

**Possible Solution**

We've seen other services/APIs provide [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) ranges or files containing CIDR ranges, which we can then whitelist and dynamically refresh/use for this whitelisting.

**Where I've looked**

I've searched the Stack Exchange API documentation, the Stack Apps site, and the `stackexchange-api` tag on Stack Overflow for this, as well as several google searches (as it turns out these are seldom about Stack Exchange, but instead unrelated topics hosted on Stack Exchange).

**Question**

Is there a list of CIDR ranges that we can whitelist?  Are they published anywhere?  Is there another approach which is recommended that would allow me to access Stack Exchange APIs from behind a firewall?

Comment: Very similar question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342944/282094

Comment: @Rob, Would you recommend I leverage that post somehow?  My question is about IP address ranges, specifically, while that and the post it is marked as duplicating are not concerned with IP address ranges (342944's question asks in the title, but the body of the question explains that he's actually looking for "URLs" instead).

Comment: IP addresses can change and may not be contiguous, while URLs remain more constant (less frequently changed); and the Firewall should cache the DNS, so it's not looked up each time only if there's a failure (404).

Comment: @Rob, in other cases we've found that large hosts like AWS and Microsoft block off public IP ranges for their servers and that these ranges may change as infrequently as monthly, with updates made available in a file we can periodically download, while DNS on the other hand is used for load balancing and will return a subset of these for load balancing, which may change fairly frequently.  The problem is the firewall does in essence cache the IP, while the API client grabs a new one each time which may not yet be whitelisted.

Comment: @Rob, see here for an example with Azure -- in this case it is weekly that they expect you to update the IP ranges, while DNS lookups have been found to vary throughout the day: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Comment: In keeping with the terminology you are using you would create FQDN Tags, not Service Tags. There is no specific API call to download a (your) "subscription", by following the "duplicate link" in the banner of the URL in my prior comment the closest you can get is: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites - which you would massage with a script. Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/fqdn-tags https://www.computersolutionseast.com/blog/microsoft-azure/comparing-azure-firewall-with-nsgs-for-network-security/  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/service-tags

Comment: For the second question, "another approach", that would probably be best answered on: https://superuser.com/questions

Comment: @Rob my question is whether official IP address ranges exist for StackExchange APIs, similar to the one provided my Microsoft for their services or if StackExchange recommends an alternative to using IP ranges which would accomplish the same goal.  Are you speaking on behalf of StackExchange to say that no such IP ranges exist and/or that the recommendation of StackExchange is to try to keep up with DNS changes or couple it tightly with processing the outbound request as suggested by user 350567 (iBug says Reinstate Monica) below? Are you pointing out an issue with my question?

Comment: I'm sticking with my first comment and I am not an employee.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you can set up an HTTP / TLS reverse proxy in a DMZ, configure domain (hostname) whitelist on that proxy (e.g. [sniproxy](https://github.com/dlundquist/sniproxy) or HAProxy) and then resolve `api.stackexchange.com` onto that proxy. This has the additional benefit that it works for any external service and doesn't require a published IP address range list (and therefore no need to update your firewall rules periodically).

I've been doing this in my organization for some time, though not for security purposes. We use Debian as our routers so managing these requires just Linux knowledge.

I'm just sharing my alternative solution here. Of course an official response is the right answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I'm hoping to hear an official response on the ip ranges, like you suggested, but am grateful for the alternative to consider, which nicely addresses the problem of keeping these ranges up to date.